# MOSS 2007 crawling documents stored in external database

Tags: 2007, search, crawling

Anybody knows if the BDC can crawl the content of a document that is stored in a blob field in an external SQL Server database? The purpose is to integrate a DMS into Sharepoint's search.

I know I can use the BDC to plug the search to an external database, but what about the content of the document?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't believe that BDC can do that. You would probably have to write a custom protocol handler for the custom DMS. The good news is that this might allow you to use the other DMS's API, rather than going to the database directly.

Comment: I had the feeling it couldn't, because the BDC has no way to know the content type of the binary. We were trying to crawl a database that had an export of the data meaningful to the integration, not the complete DMS database ;)

Comment: Ah! Then yes, even if you can get the binary stream, handling it will be a pain.